# CSS tooltip on image is messed

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Why is this text after using `display:relative` in `.tooltip:hover span` messed ? I want to make my page selative to svk.png. Not fixed positions.
[image]

html

```
<figure>
     <img class="slovensko" src="svk.png" alt="mapa slovenska">
    </figure>
    <div>
    <p> <a class="tooltip" href="#">
    <img id="ZilPic" src="circle.png" alt="">
    <span id="ZilTool">text<br>
        texttexttexttext<sup>2</sup><br>
        texttexttexttexttext<br>
        texttexttexttexttexttext<br>
        texttexttexttexttext<br>
        texttexttexttexttext<br>
        texttexttexttexttexttext<br>    
    </span>
    </a></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't understand you question. And there is no such property `display:relative`

Comment: Sory ... there should be position:relative; ... i mean  when i change it to realative ... that it will mess that text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the problem of the follow rules, and the `<br>` tags causes the mess up.

```
.tooltip span {
    padding:14px 20px;
}

.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline;
}
```

If you change the `span` to `block` element, problem solved.

```
.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit:** updated working demo http://jsfiddle.net/pau79oLv/